# What technique is most appropriate to "choose" best of multiple options based on a set of requirements

Tags: self-study

I have a set of generic product features/attributes defining a set of functionality requirements (my “wants/needs"). Any number of available products potentially satisfy my requirements at some given/calculable cost. My objective is to find the best match of my requirements at the lowest cost (normally financial). 
I need some direction guidance on using an appropriate methodology and technique(s) which I can study/learn and apply to an automated decision making process. I thank you in advance for any help you are able to provide.

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about an *optimization* problem. It all comes to the problem when you have some function which you want to minimize/maximize. In your case, you would come up with a cost function, that is what you want to optimize. It can be, i.e., match quality divided by total value or something like that. Afterwards, there are as many options as you can imagine. I'd suggest to look into genetic algorithms.